# Community bot deleting questions from new users too aggressively?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, automatic-deletion

I sometimes answer questions from people new to our trade. Like this one, for example.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69752397/how-to-display-default-image-when-users-photo-is-null-or-empty-in-php   (My purpose is to encourage people to think more broadly about what they're doing, and to encourage them.)

But, while I was tidying up my answer, the community bot deleted the question when it was about 12 minutes old. There were a couple of downvotes. There may have been some flags I couldn't see, but there weren't any close votes.

What is the community bot's policy here?  How can a person like me avoid wasting time on questions that don't match the policy?

Could it be a bug?

Comment: It looks like the asker's account got deleted.

Answer (score 14):

It's not a bug. As [Suraj Rao noticed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412633/community-bot-deleting-questions-from-new-users-too-aggressively#comment876040_412633), the account associated with that question was removed. In fact, the question was implicitly deleted (because it was negatively-scored) as part of my deletion of a sockpuppet (question-ban evasion) account.

A question like this would *not* normally be deleted so quickly; the rules for automatic deletion are given here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba.

I'll undelete the question for now, but you should obviously not expect any response or interaction with the asker. And it may well be automatically deleted in time, following the above-linked criteria.

Finally, I'd be remiss to note (without actually having reviewed your answer, since I lack the domain expertise to do so competently anyway) that you are still required to post complete answers to the question, regardless of how you judge the experience level of the asker. "Hint" answers are not sufficient here. However, it totally makes sense to tailor your answers to the perceived experience level of the asker, going into more or less detail as you think is appropriate.

Comment: So, why undelete the question if it will be automatically be deleted, and it has negative score ?

Comment: Because maybe O. Jones wants to try his hand at salvaging the question, which could get it some upvotes and save it from deletion. Or maybe he wants to find a duplicate where he could repost his answer. I don't know. Point is, there was no reason for this to have been deleted, it was only deleted by chance, because it was associated with an account that was being removed for a completely unrelated reason (vote fraud). Under normal circumstances, it would not have been eligible for deletion yet, so there's no real justification for deleting it now. @Elikill58

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thanks for clarification !

Comment: Also, as has been pointed out to me by someone who actually read the document that I linked to... that Q&A is not eligible for automatic deletion by the Roomba because it's not closed and it has an answer.

Comment: The answer isn't upvote so Roomba will remove it ? If it was accepted or upvoted it will not ?

Comment: @Elikill58 The link in the post says that it will Roomba by the 30-days or the 365-days rule if conditions are met. One of those conditions is "has no answers". The 9-days rule does not apply unless "question was closed".

Comment: @Elikill58 - The answer would have to receive downvotes in order to be eligible to be deleted.  Answers that are not simply upvoted are never "Roomba"

Comment: Yes, it's because the question isn't closed. I was not thinking about this

Comment: I understand why you undeleted it, but it turns out that the community doesn't think it's a stellar question or one that can be improved into something useful.

Comment: That does not surprise me in the least. Fortunately, the community can still delete it, as moderator undeletion doesn't block community deletion.

Answer (score 1):

I saw that happen as I was trying to add another comment at the time. The question got deleted because it was asked against the rules of Stack Overflow. The account got deleted by a moderator and the question was removed together with it. The system deleted it as the score was negative at the time and there were no positively scoring answers.

> How can a person like me avoid wasting time on questions that don't match the policy?

That's tough to answer, as you never know whether the asker broke some rules or not. If you think the question is written in a really good way and asks a topic that hasn't been covered yet on Stack Overflow, you can ask moderator's to make an exception and undelete the question. However, you should have upvoted it too if you think it's a useful question. A question with positive score would have been preserved during account deletion.

So to make sure you are not wasting time, look for questions with a positive score. If you find a question with a 0 score that you think makes a good addition to our knowledge base then upvote it.

In this case, the question is not so great. This is clearly evident in its score. Currently, it sits at +0/-11.